# Git push, Error 77, "Cannot access URL"

Tags: git

I've a local repository and i want to add a remote repo to it.
I've been using

```
git remote add --track master origin https://username@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git
```

and if I want to push to that repo, I'm getting this Error:

> error: Cannot access URL https://username@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git, return code 77
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: What does `git push origin master -v` say?

Comment: Pushing to https://username@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git
error: Cannot access URL https://username@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git, return code 77
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git'

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're using and old version of git: `git --version`

Old versions are known to have some problems with https pushing

Check [git Requirements](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/git-requirements)